# VBA code Adding a cell contains date and a cell contains a number, getting mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

Hi I am Trying to add to cells together and compare them against another cell but I get a type mismatch. 
first cell is a date, the one being added is a number"as in number of days" and the third one being compared is a date also. 
but I get type mismatch.
my code is below

```
Sub Macro1()
Macro1 Macro

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim p As Integer

    Dim rowRange As Range
    Dim colRange As Range

    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rowRange = wks.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

    For i = 7 To 189
        p = 0
        For q = 8 To LastRow
            If [aq] = [si] Then
                If [cq] + [ui] >= [xi] Then
                    [oq] = 1
                Else
                    p = p + [dq]
                    [qq] = 0
                End If
             End If
         Next q     
     Next i   
End Sub
```

`[cq]` is a cell that contains date

`[ui]` is a cell that contains number

`[xi]` is a cell that contains date

Comment: Where do you declare/define `cq`, `ui`, `xi`?

Comment: @BruceWayne  - my crystal ball tells me they are named ranges but I need to get it into the shop for a vagueness test.

Comment: Are you sure that those cells contain dates and not a text string that looks like a date?

Comment: Are you saying that `[aq] = [si]` is the equivalent of `cells(q, "A") = cells(i, "S")` ?

Comment: yeah Im new to VBA and excel Macros by [cq] I mean Cell Cq and so on

Comment: @BruceWayne they are my cells, I am iteratin over cells so I have cell Cq and so on

Comment: @ScottCraner yeah I put all the type date in the active sheet so Column U, X and C are all date types

Comment: Try it as `cells(q, "A") = cells(i, "S")`.

Comment: ^^^^ `[namedrange]` is short hand to refer to a named range.  You can do `[A1]` but when using variables you need to use `Cells()` as above or `Range("A" & i)`  the short hand does not work with variables.

Comment: @ScottCraner I changed what you suggested now the code is working without any bugs but nothing happens? any idea ?!

Answer (score 2):

Try it as `cells(q, "A") = cells(i, "S")`.

```
    For i = 7 To 189
    p = 0
    For q = 8 To LastRow
         'If [aq] = [si] Then
         If cells(q, "A") = cells(i, "S") Then
            'If [cq] + [ui] >= [xi] Then
            If cells(q, "C") + cells(i, "U") >= cells(i, "X") Then
                '[oq] = 1
                cells(q, "O") = 1
            Else
                'p = p + [dq]
                p = p + cells(q, "D")
                '[qq] = 0
                cells(q, "Q") = 0
            End If
         End If
         Next q

      Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "DateAdd" function. Instructions here: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php

Example:

```
Sub add_dates()


    Dim dateOne As Date
    Dim dateTwo As Date
    Dim lngDays As Long


    dateOne = "1/1/2018"
    lngDays = 2
    dateTwo = "1/3/2018"

    Dim result As Boolean
    If DateAdd("d", lngDays, dateOne) >= dateTwo Then
        MsgBox ("Greater than or equal to")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Less than")
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: ultimately with `"d"` it does not matter as dates are the number of days since `12/31/1899` so with the old order you were adding `43101` days to `1/2/1900` which is the same as adding `2` days to `1/1/2018`   It would matter if it were any other time scale.  You do not want to add `43101` months to `1/2/1900`.

Comment: @ScottCraner,  AH, that makes sense. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @ScottCraner the problem is d is an integer value in a specific cell for example cell Ui which i is a variable

Comment: @ShahinTaghikhani not my answer